# Download public salesforce Knowledge Article?

Tags: salesforce

Salesforce publishes their server IP list here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501

However this url doesn't actually contain the IP whitelist, but rather calls a ton of javascript which loads a knowledge article that contains the text I am interested in.

I would like to get that text programmatically, without having to use selenium or other browser mimicking techniques. There must be a way to access the knowledge article directly, either with a download URL or via API. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Screen scraping might be the only way :/ But upvote https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000ECnwQAG

Comment: Done, looks like that FR has been sitting around for 2 years though so in the meantime I think you are right about needing a screen scraper.